# Nginx map for part of URI

Tags: nginx

I want a mapping like

```
map $name $id {
    Bob 1;
}
```

(scheme+domain is `$scheme://$host`).

I want to redirect `/$name/foo` to `/bar?param=$id`.

How can I do this? In examples I only see full URIs in the map. I would prefer not to have

```
map $uri $mapped_uri {
    /Bob/foo /bar?param=1;
    /Joe/foo /bar?param=2;
}
```

because that would be duplicating the hardcoded parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use anther map to capture the `$name` variable. These happen early in the cycle and can help avoid regex locations which can cause problems when your config scales.

```
map $uri $name {
    ~^/([^/]+)/foo$ $1;
}

map $name $id {
    Bob 1;
    Joe 2;
}

server {
    if ($id) {
        return 302 /bar?param=$id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution! What would you suggest if I need to redirect to certain URL if the request came under `map $uri $name`, but there was no corresponding entry? I don't think a default magic value is a good idea, because that might be a valid value in the future.

Comment: This is even more elegant solution than mine, I didn't tumble to use two `map` directives, +1

Comment: @onepiece After the first `if` block you can use the second one: `if ($name) { return 302 some_url_for_unknown_name; }`. It will be processed if the `$id` variable is empty (no corresponding name in the second `map` table), but the `$name` is not empty (request URI satisfies the first `map` regex).

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
map $name $id {
    Bob 1;
    Joe 2;
    ...
    default "some_value_for_unknown_name";
}

server {
    ...
    location ~ ^/([^/]+)/foo$ {
        set $name $1;
        rewrite ^ /bar?param=$id last;
    }
    ...
}
```

More strict version with the hardcoded set of predefined names can be something like `location ~ ^/(Bob|Joe|...)/foo$ { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, modified using the anwser from [Cole Tierney](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58866680/nginx-map-for-part-of-uri#answer-58869152).
I needed to strip the beginning of the uri.

```
map $request_uri $request_uri_path {
    ~^(?:/v2)?(.*)$ $1;
}

server {
    location /v2 {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1$request_uri_path;
    }
}
```

The regex starts with an optional start of "/v2" and only uses everything that comes after that.
So /v2/example.js would become /example.js.